# TextEncoder / TextDecoder not round tripping

Tags: javascript, unicode

I'm definitely missing something about the TextEncoder and TextDecoder behavior.  It seems to me like the following code should round-trip, but it doesn't seem to:

```js
new TextDecoder().decode(new TextEncoder().encode(String.fromCharCode(55296))).charCodeAt(0);
```

Since I'm just encoding and decoding the string, the char code seems like it should be the same, but this returns 65533 instead of 55296.  What am I missing?

Comment: Considering 55296 is the first value this happens for, I suspect it has to do with the way unicode surrogates are handled (since 0xd800 is the first surrogate); I'm just surprised that `String.fromCharCode(55296).charCodeAt(0)` round-trips just fine, but TextEncoding does not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on some spelunking, the `TextEncoder.encode()` method appears to [take an argument of type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder/encode) `USVString`, where USV stands for Unicode Scalar Value. According to [this page](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/#unicode_scalar_value), a USV cannot be a high-surrogate or low-surrogate code point.

Also, according to MDN:

> A USVString is a sequence of Unicode scalar values. This definition
> differs from that of DOMString or the JavaScript String type in that
> it always represents a valid sequence suitable for text processing,
> while the latter can contain surrogate code points.

So, my guess is your `String` argument to `encode()` is getting converted to a `USVString` (either implicitly or within `encode()`). Based on [this page](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#es-USVString), it looks like to convert from `String` to `USVString`, it first converts it to a `DOMString`, and then [follows this procedure](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#javascript-string-convert), which includes replacing all surrogates with `U+FFFD`, which is the code point you see, `65533`, the ["Replacement Character"](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm).

The reason `String.fromCharCode(55296).charCodeAt(0)` works I believe is because it doesn't need to do this `String -> USVString` conversion.

As to why `TextEncoder.encode()` was designed this way, I don't understand the unicode details well enough to attempt to explain, but I suspect it's to simplify implementation since the only output encoding it supports seems to be UTF-8, in an `Uint8Array`. I'm guessing requiring a `USVString` argument without surrogates (instead of a native UTF-16 `String` possibly *with* surrogates) simplifies the encoding to `UTF-8`, or maybe makes some encoding/decoding use cases simpler?

Comment: What's interesting is that TextEncoder used to support non utf-8 encoders, but this support was dropped.  Overall, it seems like there are some strange caveats to the use of TextEncoder.

Comment: Yeah, some of the newer JS APIs seem over-complicated and oddly limited.

Answer (score 0):

For those (like me) who aren't sure what "unicode surrogates" are:

## The problem

The character code 55296 is **not a valid character** *by itself*. So this part of the code is already a problem:

```
String.fromCharCode(55296)
```

Since there is no valid character at that charCode, the `.fromCharCode` function returns the error character "�" instead, which happens to have the code 65533.

Codes like 55296 are only valid as the *first* element of a *pair* of codes. Pairs of codes are used to represent the characters that didn't fit in Unicode's [Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane). (There are a *lot* of characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane, so they need two 16-bit numbers to encode them.)

For example, here is a valid use of the code 55296:

```
console.log(String.fromCharCode(55296, 57091)
```

It returns the character "", from the ancient [Etruscan alphabet](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%F0%90%8C%83).

## The solution

This code will round-trip correctly:

```
const code = new TextEncoder().encode(String.fromCharCode(55296, 57091));
console.log(new TextDecoder().decode(code).charCodeAt(0));  // Returns 55296
```

But beware: `.charCodeAt` only returns the *first part of the pair*. A safer option might be to use [String.codePointAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt) to convert the character into a **single 32-bit code**:

```
const code = new TextEncoder().encode(String.fromCharCode(55296, 57091));
console.log(new TextDecoder().decode(code).codePointAt(0));  // Returns 66307
```

Comment: I don't know much about Unicode surrogates, but my answer is based on the definition: when your Metaverse parents get cloned and replaced by drone software equivalents while you're busy getting a snack from the fridge. Unicode surrogates

Comment: `String.fromCharCode(55296)` does actually return a string containing a single character with code 55296.  If you do `String.fromCharCode(55296).charCodeAt(0)` you get 55296.  The problem that I was running into was that I had a string with such codepoints, and there isn't an easy way to convert it to byte.

Comment: You are simply wrong as `String.fromCharCode(55296).charCodeAt(0)` does indeed return 55296. The '�' character is just the way the browser (or your OS idk) renders it

Comment: @FrankZ., the round-trip doesn't prove anything. `String.fromCharCode(55296)` is not a valid character. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U+D800_to_U+DFFF

Comment: I don't know why you're trying to justify yourself, you said "Since there is no valid character at that charCode, the `.fromCharCode` function returns the error character "�" instead, which happens to have the code 65533.", which is plain simply wrong, it does return the character with the code you passed in regardless of whether it's a valid unicode character or not, and this is literally proven by the round tripping, the way your os renders it is not relevant here